# Help needs with taking the derivative of a Product

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$ Y(E)  = \frac{EK}{2r}( r + \sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}})$

I have tried this so many time but I am total lost here I get as far as

$ \frac{dY}{dE} = k/2 + k\frac{r^2-4rE/k} + Ek\4 r^2 -4rE\k $

Answer (score 2):

It's rather simple; all you need to do is use the product rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$

And the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(g(x)))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$

From here, it's just brute force.

$$\frac{dY}{dE}=\frac{K}{2r}\bigg(r+\sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}}\bigg)-\frac{EK}{2r}\Bigg(\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}}}\Bigg)\frac{4r}{K}$$

Which simplifies down to

$$\frac{dY}{dE}=\frac{K}{2r}\bigg(r+\sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}}\bigg)-\frac{E}{\sqrt{r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}}}$$

Hope that helped - if you're confused about anything, please let me know!

Edit: In response to your comment, I'll go ahead and show my steps. Sorry for the late reply!

Anyway, we can rewrite the original expression as the following:

$$Y(E)=\frac{EK}{2r}\bigg(r+\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)$$

Now, distributing our front term and taking the derivative with respect to E, we get

$$\frac{dY}{dE}=\frac{d}{dE}\frac{EK}{2}+\frac{d}{dE}\frac{EK}{2r}\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

The left part of the sum is easy to evaluate, giving us

$$\frac{dY}{dE}=\frac{K}{2}+\frac{d}{dE}\frac{EK}{2r}\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Using the product rule, we get

$$\frac{dY}{dE}=\frac{K}{2}+\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{d}{dE}\frac{EK}{2r}+\frac{EK}{2r}\frac{d}{dE}\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

The left side of this sum is again rather easy to evaluate, whereas the right side proves to be a bit trickier. Before I evaluate it, however, I'd like to remind you of the power rule, in case you're not very familiar with it:

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$$

Note that this power rule works for any n, not just integers. That means that it will also work for our square root term. This, when combined with the chain rule, will prove to be a formidable force against this problem.

$$\frac{dY}{dE}=\frac{K}{2}+\frac{K}{2r}\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{EK}{2r}\frac{1}{2}\bigg(r^2-\frac{4rE}{K}\bigg)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\bigg(-\frac{4r}{K}\bigg)$$

And now, with that glorious display of mathematical carnage, all our differential terms have vanished! From here, we just simplify and rewrite, giving us the original answer I gave you.

Comment: Can you add your intermediate steps to how you simplified?

Comment: Also where did you get the minus from ? I get a plus Ek\2r

Comment: This is what I get after simplifying $ \frac{E}{2} +\frac{E}{2r} \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{4rE}{K} + \frac{E}{ \sqrtr^2-4rE\k} $